# Odata $expand won't work on specific queries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

We're making an ASP.NET Core API for a web app that should get a list of users (and expand a specific field) from a SQL Server database with Entity Framework. It works until we specify which user Id we want in the URL.

Here is the `Startup` class:

```cs
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
            builder.EntitySet<Character>("Characters");
            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<GaiumContext>(opts => opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString:Gaium"]));
            services.AddOData();
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc(b =>
            {
                b.EnableDependencyInjection();
                b.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(100).Count();
                b.MapODataServiceRoute("api", "api", GetEdmModel());
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is the `DbContext`:

```cs
public class GaiumContext : DbContext
    {
        public GaiumContext(DbContextOptions<GaiumContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Character> Characters { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(c => c.Characters);
        }
    }
```

Finally, the controller `UsersController` :

```
public class UsersController : ODataController
    {
        private GaiumContext _context;

        public UsersController(GaiumContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_context.Users);
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public IActionResult Get(long key)
        {
            return Ok(_context.Users.Find(key));
        }
    }
```

The user object looks like this:

```
Users {
  id: int,
  name: string,
  Characters: [{
    id: int,
    name: String
  }]
}
```

Here's a query for all the users:

```
GET: https://localhost:44323/api/users?$expand=Characters
```

In this case the query works fine and we do receive the list of users, as well as their Characters field.

```
{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44323/api/$metadata#Users","value":[{"Id":1,"Username":"Ok","Characters":[{"Id":1,"Name":"bigusernamesmoke"}]}]}
```

But when we try to get the result for one specific user, using their ID, the Characters list is empty:

```
GET: https://localhost:44323/api/users/1?$expand=Characters
```

```
{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44323/api/$metadata#Users/$entity","Id":1,"Username":"Ok","Characters":[]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the `Find(key)` method returns a **single** `Book` instead of a **queryable** object :

> return Ok(_context.Users.Find(key));

If I change your code to return a **`SingleResult`** as below:

```
[EnableQuery]
public SingleResult<User> Get(long key)
{
    var query = _context.Users.Where(p => p.Id == key);
    return SingleResult.Create(query);
}
```

it works fine for me.